# What is the difference between soql for loop vs soql list

Tags: for-loop, salesforce, apex, soql

As per the documentation it mentions ) (soql for loop) retrieves all sObjects using a call to query and queryMore whereas (list for loop) retrieves a number of objects records. It is advisable to use (soql for loop) over (list for loop) to avoid heap size limit error.

Total Heap Size Limit :  6 M.B Synchronous and 12 M.B Asynchronous.

In below case, let say each record is taking 2 K.B so 50,000 will take 50,000*2=100000 K.B (100 M.B approx in conList) which will cause heap size limit error as the allowed limit is 6 M.B for synchronous.

```
list<contact> conList=new list<contact>();

conList=[Select id,phone from contact];
```

To avoid this we should use "SOQL for loop" as con variable highlighted below will have 1 record at a time i.e 2k.B of data at a time thus preventing heap size limit error.

```
for (List<Contact> con: [SELECT id, name FROM contact]){    

}
```

Question - What does it mean that "SOQL for loop" as con variable highlighted below will have 1 record at a time i.e 2k.B of data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be that you can't use the retrieved records outside of the for loop if you go with that. When you store the records in the List, you can use that list to manipulate that in the for loop, but you can also use it in other operations at a later time.
To give you an example:

```
List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 100];
for(Contact c:conList){
    c.Title = Mr/Mrs;
}
update conList;//I am able to use the same list in the update call.
```